# How to compute feature-space distance?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

some CV research papers use nearest neighbors techniques to compare images, such as [PROGRESSIVE GROWING OF GANS FOR IMPROVED QUALITY, STABILITY, AND VARIATION](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.10196.pdf)

> Next five rows: Nearest neighbors found from the training data, based on **feature-space distance**.

What is "feature-space distance" in this context? How to compute the feature-space distance" in this context?

Could someone please give a hint?

Answer (score 1):

They mean that there’s some kind of distance measurement$^{\dagger}$ on their feature space, and that allows them to determine how far two points are from each other. However, the paper should specify somewhere what kind of distance function they use: Euclidean distance $(l_2)$, taxicab distance $(l_1)$ etc. If it doesn’t, shame on the authors for failing to give this important information, not on you for failing to guess what they did. (The distance function may be given in a reference.)

Perusing the article, there are several explicit references to particular types of distance. They seem particularly interested in Wasserstein distance.

$^{\dagger}$I mostly mean a metric space, though there may be exotic situations where some distance measure is useful but lacks some properties of a true metric. (KL divergence, which lacks symmetry, comes to mind.)